# Comparison method violates its general contract - how to avoid it

Tags: java, sorting, exception, illegalargumentexception, timsort

I know there are probably a few really good explanations of that issue, but I still cannot apply it to my code. How to avoid that error in my case? Here is my code:

```
        sampleList.sort((o1, o2) -> {
            try {
                if (o1.getDate() == null || o2.getDate() == null) return 0;
                int i = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy").parse(o1.getDate()).compareTo(new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy").parse(o2.getDate()));
                return i;
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                logger.error("Sorting failed", e);
            }
            return 0;
        });
```

sampleList is a list of type, which contains date in string. And here is an exception I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeLo(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.sort(Unknown Source)
    at
```

If you have suggestions on how to solve it, please share it with me. Thank you.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error.  Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparator doesn't deal with nulls and unparseable dates correctly. Consider the following case:

Suppose you have two non null dates d1 and d2 and a null d3.
Suppose d1 > d2.

You thus have

```
d1 > d2
d1 == d3
d2 == d3
```

So, if d1 and d2 are both equal to d3, they should also be equal to each other, but they're not.

Start by transforming all your strings to dates or null.

Then use a comparator which considers all null values as bigger (or lower) than all non null values. `Comparator` has utility methods to transform a comparator of non-null objects into a comparator which deals with nulls by putting them all first or last.

Answer (score 1):

The javadoc of [`compare(T o1, T o2)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-) says:

> the implementor must ensure that `compare(x, y)==0` implies that `sgn(compare(x, z))==sgn(compare(y, z))` for all `z`.

Your implementation fails to meet that part of the contract.

If you have `x = null, y = 1, z = 2`, your implementation of "null equals anything", means:

```java
compare(x, y) == 0   // Precondition met
//    0

sgn(compare(x, z)) == sgn(compare(y, z))   // Contract violated!
//      0                   -1
```